# Small Enterprise DNS Caching Server Recommendation

Tags: domain-name-system

I currently administrate an office of about 70 users and will grow to about 100 users in the next year.

My current topology is:

- The DNS Option in DHCP is now pointing to Google Public DNS.
- There is no server running in my office

I have read on some sites that it is recommended to use a local DNS Caching Server or a DNS Forwarder Server, then I have built a Bind9 DNS Caching server for testing purpose but I haven't seen any advantages of deploying it yet.

So is there any advantage of local DNS and should I build one for my office?

Comment: Doing so will improve the performance for your users. Also, you will have a better availability in the unlikely event that 8.8.8.8 goes down. You probably want a caching/forwarding nameserver.

Comment: I think the question you should be formulating is "how should I be configuring my DNS server" after explaining how you've got it configured.

Answer (score 1):

Basically if you need some local domain for your office (eg devserver.mydomin.name), then only use local DNS. In your particular case, it is not necessary. It doesn't matter there is 100 or 1000 staff, google public DNS will easily handle. As there is no server in your office why to increase cost by adding physical hardware?

Comment: Also, specifically Bind would be a significant cost in terms of maintenance.